# Let $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ a convex function on $U$ (an open convex set of $\mathbb{R}^d$) which is

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, partial-derivative

differentiable at $x\in U$.

We want to prove that if $x\in U$ is a global minimum for $f$, then for all $y\in U$ : $\mathrm{d}_x f.(y-x)=0$.

Using just the fact that $U$ is a convex set and $x\in U$ is in particular a local minimum, I proved that for all $y\in U$ : $\mathrm{d}_x f.(y-x)\ge 0$.

Maybe to get the equality, I have to use the fact that $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ ?

*$\underline{PS}$ : I know that it is a general statement for differentiable functions on an open set which have a local extremum. But here I want a proof which uses convexity.*

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why don't you use the general statement for differentiable functions? You can then use convexity to show that the local extremum must be a global minimum.

Comment: @LinAlg Indeed why not ! But I struggle with using an auxiliary function well defined ... For instance as $U$ is convex all the points of the form $x+k(y-x) \in U$ with $k\in [0,1]$. So the function : $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \ ; \ k \mapsto f(x+k(y-x))$ is not defined on an open set centered on $0$.

Comment: $U$ is open so you can actually extend the domain to $[-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Anyway, in one dimension it doesn't really matter that the function is defined on the compact interval $[0,1]$, because it is easy to define one-sided limits.

Comment: @peek-a-boo As $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$, there exists $r>0$ such that $\mathcal{B}(x,r)\subseteq U$. Then we want to find an open interval $I$ which contains $0$ and such that the function is defined on $I$ ?

Comment: yes (geometrically this should be clear: draw an open convex set $U$, like an ellipse in the plane, and draw two points $x,y$ and the line segment joining them. Also, draw two points $x_0,y_0$ which are very close to $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $x_0,x,y,y_0$ all lie on the same line; you can do this since $U$ is open. Now, parametrize the line segment joining $x_0$ and $y_0$). In short: convexity mean the line segement joining $x$ and $y$ is contained in the set; openness means you can extend the line segment in both directions by a little bit while remaining in the set.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ok the line segment $[x_0,y_0]$ is a similarity of  the line segment $[x,y]$ with the conditions that $\vert \vert x-x_0\vert \vert<r$ and $\vert \vert y-y_0\vert \vert <r'$ !?

Comment: yes exactly, where $r,r'$ are small enough so those open balls are contained in the open $U$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo It will give for instance $I = ]-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon[ \ $; $\epsilon >0$